# installation of archlinux on a new SSD is not booting

Tags: linux, ubuntu, arch-linux

I have a running ubuntu 11.10 system on my asus G73J labtop.
I repaced my HDD with a new SSD from pattriot and install arch linux on it.
After the installation the reboot didn't work.

What could be a likely cause?

1. Wrong BIOS setting?
2. Incompatible Hardware of the SSD
3. Software Problem of arch linux

I could install ubuntu on the new SSD to check if it is working, i.e. booting from ubuntu, but is there a better way?

-- edit:
the BIOS shows 3 HDDs on the SATA bus, although I have only 2 HDDs in my labtop. maybe this is related...

Comment: at which stage did the reboot fail? grub, kernel? what were the errors?

Comment: just a blank cursor. this happens also with a usb stick if I install the arch linux wrongly on "/dev/sda1", instead of "/dev/sda". It doesn't get to grub, just a bank cursor is shown.

Comment: seems bios related then, maybe the boot order is messed up.

Comment: thanks again for the help. I can choose manually a device to boot from, like boot "USB2stick", "PATTRIOT". Like a boot menu where you can choose. So I am pretty sure that it tries to boot from the SSD.

Comment: strange indeed, i never installed arch so i don't know exactly. maybe this is related to a messed up partition table. you should check it with a live cd and parted (not gparted). try to remove the other hdd and see what happens then.

Comment: I recently had a similar issue with Archlinux, so I am curious whether you solved your problem and how. (my install works on a standard HD, but does not on an SSD following the same pocedure)